# I used dreamweaver to create sprite image. It works in design/live view but browser is not showing the image

Tags: css

I went through and created sprite image in dreamweaver. Everything looks good in design/live view.

But when I view it in preview browser the image doesn't show up, but when i put my mouse over where the image is suppose to be i can actually click on the link.

is this because i have not specified the size of the image? I don't understand =( Please help :(D

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without any actual code, I would suggest right-clicking the browser window, and selecting "inspect element", this will bring up the web inspector, and you can usually check for issues there. Make the inspector your best friend.

Also, it would be a lot easier to help you if we had all of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I use this website http://csssprites.com/
I would use a generator unless you have made successful sprites manually already.